# Ubuntu 14.04 slow wireless connection

Tags: 14.04, wireless, dell, xps

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Dell XPS 15 9530.

Now, everything except the wireless connection works fine. I've googled, and found [this](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2328602/ubuntu-slow-wifi.html) solution, but it didn't change anything for me (i.e. I added "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" to "/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf").

I'm not sure what next steps I should take to solve this problem. I've read somewhere that updating the kernel might help I ran the command "uname -r" and got "3.13.0-24-generic" back, which implies i have the kernel version 3.13 and not the newest 3.18 according to [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/install-linux-kernel-3-18-ubuntu/).

If anyone has an idea what to try next or can point me somewhere, that would be awesome.

Comment: May we see: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would edit the file `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and change
 `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` to
 `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8` then save, exit, reboot
This should bring back the wifi speed

You don't need to worry about kernel 3.18 as if you use the software update program, it should install the latest Ubuntu kernel and I think that is 3.13.0-46 or -47 now.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your WiFi channel on your router..

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep \(Channel
```

will output the most congregated channels. For more info please visit this page:
http://www.howtogeek.com/197268/how-to-find-the-best-wi-fi-channel-for-your-router-on-any-operating-system/